# Expecting integer

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, json

I am trying to dynamically populate data in a lightning componnet

and I getting error as Expecting Integer, while the same code works  in visualforce - `qili.planMap[plan]`

Not able to use this as well - >`{!qli.planMap[{!plan}]}`

This is COMPILE Error

> ERROR MESSAGE-  expecting a positive integer, found 'plan' at
>   column 13 of expression: qli.planMap[plan]: Source

```
   var action = component.get("c.getFamilyDetails");       
      action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var resJson = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log('MVK Family Details-->'+JSON.stringify(resJson));
            var highestFamiyPlanKey = resJson[0].highestPlan;
            component.set("v.selectedPlanValue",highestFamiyPlanKey);
            console.log('Highest Plan Key-->'+highestFamiyPlanKey);
            var highestFamilyTotal = resJson[0].planTotal[highestFamiyPlanKey];
            console.log('MVK total-->'+highestFamilyTotal);
            component.set("v.familyTotal",highestFamilyTotal);
            component.set("v.quoteLinteItems",resJson);
            console.log('resJson PlanMap-->'+resJson[0].PlanMap);
        }
```

Json Format:--

```
[  
   {  
      "Emp_dep_Id":"0032200000ADlc1AAD",
      "highestPlan":"Gold",
      "Name":"New Test Employee",
      "planMap":{  
         "Silver":125,
         "Gold":423
      },
      "planTotal":{  
         "Silver":596,
         "Gold":1688
      },
      "seq_number":1
   },
   {  
      "Emp_dep_Id":"0032200000ADltqAAD",
      "highestPlan":"Gold",
      "Name":"Test Dep Dep",
      "planMap":{  
         "Silver":235,
         "Gold":523
      },
      "planTotal":{  
         "Silver":596,
         "Gold":1688
      },
      "relation":"Spouse"
   },
   {  
      "Emp_dep_Id":"0032200000ADmNZAA1",
      "highestPlan":"Gold",
      "Name":"Mangesh Khapre Khapre",
      "planMap":{  
         "Silver":236,
         "Gold":742
      },
      "planTotal":{  
         "Silver":596,
         "Gold":1688
      },
      "relation":"Child"
   }
]
```

Can you please help

```
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.quoteLinteItems}" var="qli">
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class=" slds-text-link">{!qli.Name}</a></td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="slds-text-title slds-text-color_default">Completed</div>
                            </td>
                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.planNames}" var="plan">
                                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.selectedPlanValue == plan}">
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="slds-text-title slds-text-color_default">${!qli.planMap[plan]}*</div>
                                    </td>
                                </aura:if>                                        
                            </aura:iteration>
                            <td>
                                <div class="slds-text-title slds-text-color_default">Completed</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </aura:iteration>
```

quoteLinteItems -- is a List of Json objects

Comment: can you please show where you are fetching: ${!qli.planMap[plan]}* values...Remove $ and try it

Comment: Please include the exact error message in your post verbatim via **[edit]**.

Comment: added controller logic and json and error message.. now I am returning a wrapper class object from apex.

Comment: Do some null check .If it contains values then only try to access it

Comment: I am getting this as a compile error

Comment: what type you gave when `quoteLinteItems` attribute declration in your component?

Comment: It is List... <aura:attribute name="quoteLineItems" type="List" />

Answer (score 0):

You can find some difficulties while using the JSON object into aura:iteration.
You have to parse into a list and then use it aura iteration

Let me assume your use case is when the component initializes the table will generate,

then take an attribute:

```
<aura:attribute name="testList" type="List" default="{}"/>
```

on initializing the JS controller will be:

```
var jsonList = component.get("v.planNames");
var results=[];
for(number i=0;i<jsonList.length;i++){
   results.push(jsonList[i].your_property_name); 
}
component.set("v.testList", results);
```

Now you can replace the 'planNames' attribute with 'testList'.

That's all. Now you are ready to go. Hope your problem resolves.

Comment: It's a json object already.

Comment: Just updated the code. Please check if this resolves your problem

Comment: Thanks Sourav.. but I think add unnecessaary columns.. see I had a check to prevent that.. <aura:if isTrue="{!v.selectedPlanValue == plan}"> .. I thought of your wat of code this.but I don't think it works.. is there any way I can dynamically get the value based on the selected value..{!qli.planMap["{!v.selectedPlanValue }"]}

Comment: From where did you get the {!v.selectedPlanValue}?

Comment: It is an attribute, It is getting from lightning:combobox

Comment: Sourav.. I am thinking to create entire new Json for this now.. like this..   var quoteLineItem = component.get("v.quoteLineItems");
                var selectedPlan = component.get("v.selectedPlanValue");
                var arrCosts = [];
                for(var i=0;i<quoteLineItem.length;i++){
                    var item = {
                        "Name": quoteLineItem[i].Name,
                        "Plan": quoteLineItem[i].planMap[selectedPlan],
                        "Status":"Completed"
                    };
                    arrCosts.push(item);
                }

Comment: You can do this. 

Comment: If this resolves your problem please upvote my answer.